# Opening a wave file in Python: unknown format: 49. What's going wrong?

Tags: python, format, wave

I try to open a wave file with the `wave` module, but I keep getting the same error whatever I try.
The line with the error is the following:

```
wav = wave.open(f)
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "annotate.py", line 47, in <module>
    play(file)
  File "annotate.py", line 33, in play
    wav = wave.open(f)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\wave.py", line 498, in open
    return Wave_read(f)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\wave.py", line 163, in __init__
    self.initfp(f)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\wave.py", line 143, in initfp
    self._read_fmt_chunk(chunk)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\wave.py", line 269, in _read_fmt_chunk
    raise Error('unknown format: %r' % (wFormatTag,))
wave.Error: unknown format: 49
```

String `f` is a path to a .WAV file and it works when played in any of my media players.

I have of course imported the `wave` module.
I tried `f` both as a relative and an absolute path.
I tried replacing "WAV" by "wav".

What is the error caused by?

Comment: Is the wave file compressed?

Comment: I don't know, how can I see?

Comment: Looks like `wave` module returns that error when you try to read a 32-bit .wav files.

Comment: Are opening the file to get the data or to play the file?

Comment: @ChrisProsser In order to get data. I know that the `wave` module can't play a file.

Comment: Found two related posts: http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/open-wav-with-wave-module-732901.html and http://bugs.python.org/issue1144504. Seems like your `.wav` file is a IEEE float wave file, which is not supported yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Python's wave module works with a specific type of WAV: PCM (`WAVE_FORMAT_PCM: 0x0001`).

In your case, you're using a WAV of type `WAVE_FORMAT_GSM610` [0x0031 = hex(49)].

You can use a program like Audacity or some lib for converting codecs to change the type of the WAV file.

You can see a list of WAV types here:
https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/vlc__codecs_8h.html

Python's wave module source code:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/wave.py

Comment: This is exactly what I did to solve it. I used ffmpeg to convert the files, and `subprocess` to call it.

Comment: @Lewistrick : Can you post what command you are using to convert the files? I have also tried converting them but it isn't working.

Comment: @Leonardo Andrade the WAVE_FORMAT_PCM = 0x0001 is hard coded in wave.py If we change this to  WAVE_FORMAT_GSM610 [0x0031 = hex(49)] will this work ?

Comment: I don't know, @DSBLR. I'm not a specialist on WAVE formats. You can try but note that this will change the behaviour of a python's standard lib. Maybe not a good strategy to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, Did you solve this issue? i am using sox to convert gsm file to wave but encountering the same issue. It is avoidable using audacity, but I am unable to find any python module to directly convert gsm to wav. Kindly comment if you have resolved this using python or bash. Thanks

Comment: @pankaj and @Muhammad Usama : I solved a similar problem (converting from WAVE_FORMAT_MULAW 0x0007 to WAVE_FORMAT_PCM 0x0001) by simply using ffmpeg with the default arguments i.e. `ffmpeg -i input.wav output.wav`. After this, python's wave module could load the file. Apparently it was compressed before, because the file volume doubled in the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

The file is compressed and the `wave` module does not support this type of compression.