# Check audio's sample rate using python

Tags: python, audio, sample-rate

I have over a thousand audio files, and I want to check if their sample rate is 16kHz. To do it manually would take me forever. Is there a way to check the sample rate using python?

Comment: what format are the audio files?

Comment: WAV file. mono channel

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python has a [builtin module dealing with WAV files.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/wave.html)

You can write a simple script that will iterate over all files in some directory. something along the general lines of:

```
import os
import wave
for file_name in os.listdir(FOLDER_PATH):
    with wave.open(file_name, "rb") as wave_file:
        frame_rate = wave_file.getframerate()
        .... DO WHATEVER ....
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! Though your comment about Python 3.x strike me a bit weird since Python 2.7 [has a WAV library as well](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/wave.html). Anyway, good luck with the rest of your work :-)

Comment: Below Python version 3.4, `wave.open()` doesn't return a context manager. For older Python versions, the call can be wrapped in `contextlib.closing()`.

Answer (score 3):

For .wav files the solution might be:

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read as read_wav
import os
os.chdir('path') # change to the file directory
sampling_rate, data=read_wav("filename.wav") # enter your filename
print sampling_rate
```

Answer (score 1):

import subprocess

Most probably you already have 'ffmpeg' and 'ffprobe' installed on your system. Then  you can pipe any info about the audio from the 'ffprobe'. This might be easier than installing any additional APIs or libraries which either way will be working with ffprobe in the background.

- ffprobe allows to export results directly in the json format
- you can specify which audio parameters to output from ffprob

```py
import json
import subprocess

file_path = "your_audio_file.mp4"
out_data = "stream=sample_rate:format=0:stream_tags=0:format_tags=0"
command = f"ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -select_streams a:0 -show_entries {out_data} {file_path}"

process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()

metadata = json.loads(output)
audio_stream = metadata["streams"][0] 
sample_rate = audio_stream.get("sample_rate", None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I end up getting unknow file format error with the wave package from python. [wave-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297048/opening-a-wave-file-in-python-unknown-format-49-whats-going-wrong)

Alternatively the sox wrapper in python works for me.
[pysox](https://github.com/rabitt/pysox)

```
!pip install sox
import sox
sox.file_info.sample_rate("file1.wav")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This I have done this on windows. Installing sox in Linux could be a nightmare, because of dependency package and compatibility with Linux version.

Comment: works perfectly well on linux. Just install sox lib first: '$ sudo apt install sox'

Answer (score 0):

!pip install pydub

- from pydub.utils import mediainfo
- info=mediainfo("abc.wav")
- print(info)

Comment: I assume info contains more info than sample rate. could you add which specific method to fetch sample rate?

Answer (score 0):

I use the code given below whenever I want to find the sample rate.

```
import torchaudio
metadata = torchaudio.info('path/to/audio/file.extension')
print(metadata)
```

The output will look something like this

AudioMetaData(sample_rate=8000, num_frames=625920, num_channels=1, bits_per_sample=16, encoding=PCM_S)